# Getting this program to not print the trailing 0s

Tags: c++

I'm suppose to Use cin.getline( ...... ) to type another name into the variable sName.
Print the ascii value of each character in the char array, 1 per line. Use a while loop and look for the '\0' as a signal to end.

I can only use 3 variables, cnt1,cnt2 and sName which has to hold 30 elements and be set to my name. Then I have to overwrite it with getline.

Right now if I enter Jon Doe, it gives me 0s for the other remaining values (bc they're 0 to be fair) how can I make it so that this does not show in my output?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
char sName[30] = { "your name" };

cout << "Please enter your name or" <<  " \\0 to quit \n";
cin.getline(sName, 30);
while (sName != '\0')
{
    for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < 30; cnt1++)
    {
if (sName[cnt1] == 0)
            break;
        else {
        cout << sName[cnt1] << "\t\t";
        cout << static_cast<int>(sName[cnt1]) << endl;}

    }
break;
}
```

I get correct ascii values, but it's not properly exiting if the \0 is entered. and I don't know what else to make the while loop do to start off the program besides check for that....

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::string`? You won't have any trailing zeros to worry about.

Comment: `sName != '\0'` you're comparing a c-string to a character? Did you mean `sName[0] != '0'`? Why not use `std::string` and save some headache?

Comment: Because then it would be easier, and my professor would not approve.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Why can't you check if the current character is `0`, and if it is, break out the loop?

Comment: actually i just realized even with sName[0] != \0 its not actually terminating

Comment: isnt backlash 0 not the same as just plain 0?

Comment: You cannot enter escape sequences as input (at least not without parsing it manually). If you type `\0` at the prompt, your program will receive two characters - `\ ` (ASCII 92) and `0` (ASCII 48) (and a line ending, but `getline` takes care of it). I'm not aware of a way to input NUL character (ASCII 0) into a program.

Comment: IF that's the case, what should I be putting into the while loop to make it even do anything? I just don't see the point of a while loop in this scenario, but it's what I gotta do.

Comment: @telusive "_I just don't see the point of a while loop in this scenario, but it's what I gotta do._" From the looks of it: you just don't understand requirements, and instead of asking for clarification, or help, from your lecturer, you are just trying to cobble something up without understanding how it works, and why. Yes, the `while`, **as currently written** - serves a purpose of being an infinite loop, since it is, essentially, `while (sName != nullptr)`, and `sName`, will never be `nullptr`.

Comment: Professor is unavailable for help at any times. I have already tried to email her 3 days ago.

Comment: No, no pointers or functions are allowed.

Comment: You have to explain things to rubber ducks and computers very carefully. If you can explain something to the rubber duck, you can explain it to a computer. So With me as the rubber duck, explain what `while (sName != '\0')` does.

Comment: You cannot enter a *nul-character* from the command line. Change your prompt to simply `"Please enter your name: "`. When you press `[Enter]` input ends and `getline` automatically *nul-terminates* the string.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you've probably wanted something like code below.
istream getline will append terminating char anyway, so your message to user could be changed. Also, you can use pointer to char to loop over char array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    char sName[30] = "your name";

    cout << "\nPlease enter your name or" <<  " press enter to quit \n";
    cin.getline(sName, 30);
    char* ptr = &sName[0];
    while (*ptr != '\0') {
        cout << *ptr << "\t\t";
        cout << static_cast<int>(*ptr) << endl;
        ++ptr;
    }
}
```

Or, without using pointer to char, just indexing an array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    char sName[30] =  "your name" ;
    cout << "\nPlease enter your name or press enter to quit \n";
    cin.getline(sName, 30);
    int cnt(0);
    while (sName[cnt] != '\0') {
        cout << sName[cnt] << "\t\t";
        cout << static_cast<int>(sName[cnt]) << "\n";
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program, as-is, does not even compile on my system (macOS Mojave) with this error: 
`comparison between pointer and integer ('char *' and 'char')` on your while loop comparison.

As the error indicates, you are actually comparing the memory address of the array to a single character value. It will likely always be false.

sName is a C-string, meaning it is an array of characters that [should be] null-character terminated. This also means that your check `sName != '\0'` is bad.

Without doing your homework for you, here are some pointers.

- You cannot type '\0', `cin.getline()` is reading that as two characters '\' and '0'. If you are supposed to check whether the first character is a null character, then the user only needs to press enter (the '\0' will automatically be the first character in sName)
- You don't need nested loops. Inside your single loop, you can just check if you have a null character, it will catch it if it's the first character, and also catch it when you've reached the proper end of the entered name
- Do not include `<string>` if you are not allowed to use `std::string`
- `<iomanip>` is not needed, either
- You really don't have to do any special C-string stuff at all. You never included `<cstring>`, and you don't have to
- Future better practice tip: Try to avoid magic numbers; the 30 in your case. Declare a constant with the value you need; `const int MAX_NAME_SIZE = 30;` and use it instead. You will also only need to use it once when declaring the array. `sizeof(sName) is safer, although you could use the constant here again. The benefit is two-fold. Your code is easier to read, and if you change how big that array can be, you now only have to change it in one location. This may not be allowed given your current requirements, but you also don't need any other variables except sName to do this task.

Just so I provide a solution, I've purposely used `std::string` (can think of it as an automatically managed C-String) and some modern C++. It will, with just a little research, be easy enough to switch things around to meet your requirements. No one should be spoon-feeding specific homework solutions, it defeats the purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string sName = "Johnathan Fitzgerald Kennedy";

  std::cout << "Please type your name: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, sName);

  int cnt1 = 0;
  while (sName[cnt1] != '\0' && cnt1 < sName.size()) {
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(sName[cnt1]) << '\n';
    ++cnt1;
  }
}
```

Comment: it has to be a while loop though, a for loop would make this much easier I agree.I'm also not allowed to declare any other variables to store that 30 in. Also much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enter a *nul-character* from the command line. When the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering input a `'\n'` is generated and `getline` terminates the input, extracting the `'\n'` from the input stream but not including the `'\n'` in the buffer filled. `getline` automatically *nul-terminates* the string.

Further, your outer `while` loop is superfluous. All that is needed is:

```
#include <iostream>

#define MAXC 30

int main (void)
{   
    char sName[MAXC] = { "your name" };

    std::cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    std::cin.getline(sName, MAXC);

    for (size_t cnt1 = 0; sName[cnt1]; cnt1++)
        std:: cout << sName[cnt1] << "\t\t"
                    << static_cast<int>(sName[cnt1]) << '\n';
}
```

(**note:** avoid using *magic-numbers* in your code (e.g. `30`). If you need a constant, either `#define` one, declare a global `enum` or declare a `const int` value)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/char_getline
Please enter your name: John Q Public
J               74
o               111
h               104
n               110
                32
Q               81
                32
P               80
u               117
b               98
l               108
i               105
c               99
```

**Using a `while` Loop**

Using a `while` loop is just as easy. Using your `cnt1` variable, just increment until you reach the *nul-terminating* character, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void)
{   
    char sName[30] = { "your name" };
    size_t cnt1 = 0;

    std::cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    std::cin.getline(sName, 30);

    while (sName[cnt1]) {
            std::cout << sName[cnt1] << "\t\t";
            std::cout << static_cast<int>(sName[cnt1++]) << '\n';
    }
}
```

(**note:** I have removed the defined constant per your comment, output is the same)

Look things over an let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: im not allowed to create any other variables, so, while I understand it's a better practice, creating the variable to store 30 would make this points off. and it specifically HAS to be a while loop. Or else yes, this would be much easier :(

Comment: Technically `MAXC` isn't a variable, it is a defined constant. (meaning you cannot change it to be anything else -- it is set at compile-time, not runtime `:)` If you are concerned about the addition, just stick `30` back in where `MAXC` is now.

Comment: but it also has to be a while loop, a for loop is much simpler, but it has to be a while :(

Comment: A `while` is simple too, I'll add one.

Comment: I feel like I'm learning bad practices in this class, but she always makes her programs have like 3 named things, and that's all I'm allowed to use

Comment: Unfortunately, that is more common than not. Many teachers "teaching" C++ have never worked as a programmer in real life... That is why "peer-reviewed" sites like StackOverflow are a valuable tool for anyone learning to program...